# How enable deprecated functions in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt

I want to port a Qt4 program to Qt5 and some functions are not defined (such as QHeaderView::setMoveable), but I see in the qheaderview.h file that with some magic defines (QT_DEPRECATED_SINCE) it should be possible to reenable them.
What do I have to do in order to let QHeaderView::setMovable reappear? I do *not* want to rewrite my code if there is a way like that.

Comment: You don't need to rewrite your code, but only to replace old function names with new ones. What the problem? These deprecated functions may completely go away in the next version of Qt, so what will you do then?

Comment: That I call rewriting. As long as the producer of Qt offers a way to call the deprecated functions and I want to stay compatible also with Qt4 (and in fact the setMovable function calls setSectionsMovable() without the need for me to tweak around in my sources) I prefer this workaround

Comment: If you want Qt4 and Qt5 compatibility in a large project, which may be a good thing for a transition period, and if you want to replace all function names, you will end with a mess of preprocessor statements. If you can avoid this by a simple .pro line, that's good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add to your .pro file the following line:

```
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0
```