# In PyQt5 how do I properly move rows in a QTableView using Drag&Drop

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, drag-and-drop, qtableview

I (simply) want to be able to use a `QTableView`s Drag&Drop mechanism to move existing rows. I found lots of sources (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168610/qtableview-drag-move-rows), [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/63799/qtableview-drag-and-drop) or [here](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/67260-QTableView-move-internal-is-very-confusing)) which describe *some* aspects of dragging, dropping, inserting etc. but I'm still struggling to make it work for my case.

Here is what the solution I'm looking for should be capable of:

- work on a 'Qt-free' data structure, e.g. a list of tuples.
- operate on the data structure. i.e. when the order of items gets 
  modified in the view it should be modified in the data structure
- look and feel of standard drag&drop enabled lists:

  - select/move whole rows
  - show a drop indicator for the whole line
- Further operations like deleting/editing of cells must still be possible
  i.e. not be touched by the drag&drop approach

[This tutorial](http://apocalyptech.com/linux/qt/qtableview/) shows a solution which is *very* close to what I need but it uses a `QStandardItemModel` rather than `QAbstractTableModel` which looks semi-optimal to me because I have to operate on a 'mirrored' data structure based on `QStandardItem` which is needed by `QStandardItemModel` (am I right?)

The code which represents my current progress is appended  below.

Currently I see two possible approaches:

**Approach 1**: Implement against `QAbstractTableModel` and implement all needed events/slots to modify the underlying data structure:
* pro: most generic approach
* pro: no redundant data
* con: I don't know how to get informed about a finished drag&drop 
  operation and what index got moved where

In the code I've appended I trace all related methods I know of and print out all arguments. Here is what I get when I drag line 2 onto line 3

```
dropMimeData(data: ['application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist'], action: 2, row: -1, col: -1, parent: '(row: 2, column: 0, valid: True)')
insertRows(row=-1, count=1, parent=(row: 2, column: 0, valid: True))
setData(index=(row: 0, column: 0, valid: True), value='^line1', role=0)
setData(index=(row: 0, column: 1, valid: True), value=1, role=0)
removeRows(row=1, count=1, parent=(row: -1, column: -1, valid: False))
```

This output raises the following questions for me:

- why do `moveRow`/`moveRows` not get called? when would they be called?
- why are `insertRow`/`removeRow` not called but only `insertRows`/`removeRows`?
- what does a row index of `-1` mean?
- what can I do with mime data provided in `dropMimeData`? Should I use it to copy data later?

**Approach 2**: Use `QStandardItemModel` and modify your data in parallel to the data managed by `QStandardItemModel`.
* pro: there's a [working example](http://apocalyptech.com/linux/qt/qtableview/)
* contra: you manage a redundant data structure which has to be consistent 
  with another internally managed data structure.
* contra: didn't find out how to do that exactly neither

> Here is my current approach using `QAbstractTableModel`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None, *args):
        super().__init__(parent, *args)
        self._data = data

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self._data)

    def headerData(self, column: int, orientation, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        return (('Regex', 'Category')[column] 
                if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
                else None)

    def data(self, index, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        if role not in {QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole}:
            return None

        print("data(index=%s, role=%r)" % (self._index2str(index), self._role2str(role)))
        return (self._data[index.row()][index.column()] 
               if index.isValid()
               and role in {QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole} 
               and index.row() < len(self._data)
               else None)

    def setData(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, value, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):

        print("setData(index=%s, value=%r, role=%r)" % (self._index2str(index), value, role))
        return super().setData(index, value, role)

    def flags(self, index):
        return (
           super().flags(index) 
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
            | (QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled)
              if index.isValid() else QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags)

    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, col, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        """Always move the entire row, and don't allow column 'shifting'"""
        print("dropMimeData(data: %r, action: %r, row: %r, col: %r, parent: %r)" % (
            data.formats(), action, row, col, self._index2str(parent)))
        assert action == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction
        return super().dropMimeData(data, action, row, 0, parent)

    def supportedDragActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction

    def removeRow(self, row: int, parent=None):
        print("removeRow(row=%r):" % (row))
        return super().removeRow(row, parent)

    def removeRows(self, row: int, count: int, parent=None):
        print("removeRows(row=%r, count=%r, parent=%s)" % (row, count, self._index2str(parent)))
        return super().removeRows(row, count, parent)

    def insertRow(self, index, parent=None):
        print("insertRow(row=%r, count=%r):" % (row, count))
        return super().insertRow(row, count, parent)

    def insertRows(self, row: int, count: int, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = None):
        print("insertRows(row=%r, count=%r, parent=%s)" % (row, count, self._index2str(parent)))
        return super().insertRows(row, count, parent)

    @staticmethod
    def _index2str(index):
        return "(row: %d, column: %d, valid: %r)" % (index.row(), index.column(), index.isValid())

    @staticmethod
    def _role2str(role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole) -> str:
        return "%s (%d)" % ({
            QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: "DisplayRole",
            QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole: "DecorationRole",
            QtCore.Qt.EditRole: "EditRole",
            QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole: "ToolTipRole",
            QtCore.Qt.StatusTipRole: "StatusTipRole",
            QtCore.Qt.WhatsThisRole: "WhatsThisRole",
            QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole: "SizeHintRole",

            QtCore.Qt.FontRole: "FontRole",
            QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole: "TextAlignmentRole",
            QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole: "BackgroundRole",
            #QtCore.Qt.BackgroundColorRole:
            QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole: "ForegroundRole",
            #QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole
            QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole: "CheckStateRole",
            QtCore.Qt.InitialSortOrderRole: "InitialSortOrderRole",
        }[role], role)


class MyTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    class DropmarkerStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
        def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):
            """Draw a line across the entire row rather than just the column we're hovering over.
            This may not always work depending on global style - for instance I think it won't
            work on OSX."""
            if element == self.PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop and not option.rect.isNull():
                option_new = QtWidgets.QStyleOption(option)
                option_new.rect.setLeft(0)
                if widget:
                    option_new.rect.setRight(widget.width())
                option = option_new
            super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyle(self.DropmarkerStyle())
        # only allow rows to be selected
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        # disallow multiple rows to be selected
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.setDragEnabled(True)

        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setDropIndicatorShown(True) # default
        self.setAcceptDrops(False)           # ?
        self.viewport().setAcceptDrops(True) # ?
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)


class HelloWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        model = MyModel([("^line0", 0),
                         ("^line1", 1),
                         ("^line2", 2),
                         ("^line3", 3)])

        table_view = MyTableView()
        table_view.setModel(model)
        table_view.verticalHeader().hide()
        table_view.setShowGrid(False)

        self.setCentralWidget(table_view)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = HelloWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no clue yet how to make `QAbstractTableModel` or `QAbstractItemModel` work as described but I finally found a way to make the `QTableView` handle drag & drop and just makes the model move a row.

Here's the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class ReorderTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None, *args):
        super().__init__(parent, *args)
        self._data = data

    def columnCount(self, parent=None) -> int:
        return 2

    def rowCount(self, parent=None) -> int:
        return len(self._data) + 1

    def headerData(self, column: int, orientation, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        return (('Regex', 'Category')[column]
                if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
                else None)

    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        if not index.isValid() or role not in {QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole}:
            return None
        return (self._data[index.row()][index.column()] if index.row() < len(self._data) else
                "edit me" if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole else "")

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags:
        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        if index.row() < len(self._data):
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def supportedDropActions(self) -> bool:
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction

    def relocateRow(self, row_source, row_target) -> None:
        row_a, row_b = max(row_source, row_target), min(row_source, row_target)
        self.beginMoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row_a, row_a, QtCore.QModelIndex(), row_b)
        self._data.insert(row_target, self._data.pop(row_source))
        self.endMoveRows()


class ReorderTableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    """QTableView with the ability to make the model move a row with drag & drop"""

    class DropmarkerStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
        def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):
            """Draw a line across the entire row rather than just the column we're hovering over.
            This may not always work depending on global style - for instance I think it won't
            work on OSX."""
            if element == self.PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop and not option.rect.isNull():
                option_new = QtWidgets.QStyleOption(option)
                option_new.rect.setLeft(0)
                if widget:
                    option_new.rect.setRight(widget.width())
                option = option_new
            super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.SingleSelection)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)
        self.setStyle(self.DropmarkerStyle())

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if (event.source() is not self or
            (event.dropAction() != QtCore.Qt.MoveAction and
             self.dragDropMode() != QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)):
            super().dropEvent(event)

        selection = self.selectedIndexes()
        from_index = selection[0].row() if selection else -1
        to_index = self.indexAt(event.pos()).row()
        if (0 <= from_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            0 <= to_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            from_index != to_index):
            self.model().relocateRow(from_index, to_index)
            event.accept()
        super().dropEvent(event)


class Testing(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """Demonstrate ReorderTableView"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        view = ReorderTableView(self)
        view.setModel(ReorderTableModel([
            ("a", 1),
            ("b", 2),
            ("c", 3),
            ("d", 4),
        ]))
        self.setCentralWidget(view)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    test = Testing()
    raise SystemExit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

MyData class should be inherited from QStandardItemModel
revised your code to solve drag-drop and extension class function call issue.

```
from PyQt5 import (QtWidgets, QtCore)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QTableView)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel)


class MyModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None, *args):
        super().__init__(parent, *args)
        self._data = data

        for (index, data) in enumerate(data):
            first = QStandardItem('Item {}'.format(index))
            first.setDropEnabled(False)
            first.setEditable(False)
            second = QStandardItem(data[0])
            second.setDropEnabled(False)
            second.setEditable(False)
            self.appendRow([first, second])

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 2

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self._data)

    def headerData(self, column: int, orientation, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        return (('Regex', 'Category')[column]
                if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal
                else None)

    def data(self, index, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        if role not in {QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole}:
            return None

        print("data(index=%s, role=%r)" % (self._index2str(index), self._role2str(role)))
        return (self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
                if index.isValid() and role in {QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole} and index.row() < len(
            self._data)
                else None)

    def setData(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, value, role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole):
        print("setData(index=%s, value=%r, role=%r)" % (self._index2str(index), value, role))
        return super().setData(index, value, role)

    def flags(self, index):
        return (
            super().flags(index)
            | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
            | (QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled)
            if index.isValid() else QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags)

    def dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, col, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        """Always move the entire row, and don't allow column 'shifting'"""
        print("dropMimeData(data: %r, action: %r, row: %r, col: %r, parent: %r)" % (
            data.formats(), action, row, col, self._index2str(parent)))
        assert action == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction
        return super().dropMimeData(data, action, row, 0, parent)

    def supportedDragActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction

    def removeRow(self, row: int, parent=None):
        print("removeRow(row=%r):" % (row))
        return super().removeRow(row, parent)

    def removeRows(self, row: int, count: int, parent=None):
        print("removeRows(row=%r, count=%r, parent=%s)" % (row, count, self._index2str(parent)))
        return super().removeRows(row, count, parent)

    def insertRow(self, index, parent=None):
        print("insertRow(row=%r, count=%r):" % (row, count))
        return super().insertRow(row, count, parent)

    def insertRows(self, row: int, count: int, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = None):
        print("insertRows(row=%r, count=%r, parent=%s)" % (row, count, self._index2str(parent)))
        return super().insertRows(row, count, parent)

    @staticmethod
    def _index2str(index):
        return "(row: %d, column: %d, valid: %r)" % (index.row(), index.column(), index.isValid())

    @staticmethod
    def _role2str(role: QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole) -> str:
        return "%s (%d)" % ({
                                QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: "DisplayRole",
                                QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole: "DecorationRole",
                                QtCore.Qt.EditRole: "EditRole",
                                QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole: "ToolTipRole",
                                QtCore.Qt.StatusTipRole: "StatusTipRole",
                                QtCore.Qt.WhatsThisRole: "WhatsThisRole",
                                QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole: "SizeHintRole",

                                QtCore.Qt.FontRole: "FontRole",
                                QtCore.Qt.TextAlignmentRole: "TextAlignmentRole",
                                QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole: "BackgroundRole",
                                # QtCore.Qt.BackgroundColorRole:
                                QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole: "ForegroundRole",
                                # QtCore.Qt.TextColorRole
                                QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole: "CheckStateRole",
                                QtCore.Qt.InitialSortOrderRole: "InitialSortOrderRole",
                            }[role], role)


class MyTableView(QTableView):
    class DropMarkerStyle(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
        def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget=None):
            """Draw a line across the entire row rather than just the column we're hovering over.
            This may not always work depending on global style - for instance I think it won't
            work on OSX."""
            if element == self.PE_IndicatorItemViewItemDrop and not option.rect.isNull():
                option_new = QtWidgets.QStyleOption(option)
                option_new.rect.setLeft(0)
                if widget:
                    option_new.rect.setRight(widget.width())
                option = option_new
            super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyle(self.DropMarkerStyle())
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.setShowGrid(False)
        # only allow rows to be selected
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)
        # disallow multiple rows to be selected
        self.setSelectionMode(self.SingleSelection)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)


class HelloWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        model = MyModel([("^line0", 0),
                         ("^line1", 1),
                         ("^line2", 2),
                         ("^line3", 3)])
        table_view = MyTableView()
        table_view.setModel(model)
        self.setCentralWidget(table_view)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = HelloWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I also found this example which shows drag&drop with an `QStandardModel` you are likely referring to but it has some problems: e.g. when you fix `first = ...` to take `data[0]` and `second =` to take `data[1]` the app crashes (probably because of `data[1]` being an `int`). But still if I run your example as it is I'm ending up with lines being deleted when I try to drag & drop them..

Comment: i tried commenting out the events in MyModel class but didnt fix the drag-drop functionality issue. Code added in MyModel constructor to define data as QStandardItem and its drag-drop features is the main part of the working solution.