# Re-ordering QTableView rows that include spanned columns

Tags: python, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qtableview

I have a working drag and drop example below for reordering rows of the same column length for a qtableview using PyQt5 (with help from this StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61387248/in-pyqt5-how-do-i-properly-move-rows-in-a-qtableview-using-dragdrop)).  However I am looking to perform the same operation on a qtableview table where one or two rows have merged cells spanning the total number of columns (like the second row in the picture below).

[image]

How would be the best way to go about this?  Should I remove the merge (clearSpans) at the point of drag/drop and then do a remerge based on the cell value (though when I tried this it did not work), or is there a way to drag/drop reorder with the cell merging intact?

Here's the code which works for row data of equal columns, but fails when a row is merged

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QModelIndex

class myModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None, *args):
        super().__init__(parent, *args)
        self._data = data or []
        self._headers = ['Type', 'result', 'count']

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return len(self._headers)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                if section < 0 or section >= len(self._headers):
                    return ""
                else:
                    return self._headers[section]
        return None

    def data(self, index, role=None):

        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignHCenter

        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            return QBrush(Qt.black)
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if (self.index(index.row(), 0).data().startswith('second')):
                return QBrush(Qt.green)
            else:
                if (self.index(index.row(), 1).data()) == 'abc':
                    return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
                if (self.index(index.row(), 1).data()) == 'def':
                    return QBrush(Qt.blue)
                if (self.index(index.row(), 1).data()) == 'ghi':
                    return QBrush(Qt.magenta)

        if role in (Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole):
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
        
    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled

    def supportedDropActions(self) -> bool:
        return Qt.MoveAction | Qt.CopyAction

    def relocateRow(self, row_source, row_target) -> None:
        row_a, row_b = max(row_source, row_target), min(row_source, row_target)
        self.beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), row_a, row_a, QModelIndex(), row_b)
        self._data.insert(row_target, self._data.pop(row_source))
        self.endMoveRows()


class myTableView(QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.SingleSelection)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if (event.source() is not self or
            (event.dropAction() != Qt.MoveAction and
             self.dragDropMode() != QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)):
            super().dropEvent(event)

        selection = self.selectedIndexes()
        #self.clearSpans()
        from_index = selection[0].row() if selection else -1
        to_index = self.indexAt(event.pos()).row()
        if (0 <= from_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            0 <= to_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            from_index != to_index):
            self.model().relocateRow(from_index, to_index)
            event.accept()
        super().dropEvent(event)


class sample_data(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tv = myTableView(self)
        tv.setModel(myModel([
            ["first", 'abc', 123],
            ["second"],
            ["third", 'def', 456],
            ["fourth", 'ghi', 789],
        ]))
        self.setCentralWidget(tv)
        tv.setSpan(1, 0, 1, 3)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    test = sample_data()
    raise SystemExit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The sections of the vertical header [can be made movable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionsMovable), so there's no need to implement this functionality yourself. It obviously means the vertical header will be visible, but that can be mitigated by making the sections blank, which will result in a relatively narrow header. You could also add a keyboard shortcut to toggle the visibility of the vertical header.

Comment: @ekhumoro would this just be a case of replacing self.verticalHeader().hide() with self.verticalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True) ? Though I tried that, and the vertical header is still hidden.

Comment: No, there's a little more to it than that. I can provide an answer with a working example if you're interested. One thing I should probably mention is that moving sections around is purely *visual* - the underlying model is never modified. That shouldn't really matter in practice, though, since the header provides methods to translate from logical to visual indices. And it does bring some additional benefits - for example, it's very easy to restore the original state.

Comment: I would be really interested in a working example, and very grateful. I'm only just getting my head around the model/view setup.

Comment: Okay - I've converted my comments into an answer and included a working demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sections of the vertical header [can be made movable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionsMovable), so there's no need to implement this functionality yourself. It obviously means the vertical header will be visible, but that can be mitigated by making the sections blank, which will result in a relatively narrow header:

[image: screenshot]

Note that moving sections around (rather than rows) is purely *visual* - the underlying model is never modified. That shouldn't really matter in practice, though, since the header provides methods to translate from [logical](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#logicalIndex) to [visual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#visualIndex) indices. And it does bring some additional benefits - for example, it's very easy to return to a previous state (i.e. by using the header's [saveState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#saveState) and [restoreState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#restoreState) methods).

Below is a working demo based on your example. The rows can be re-ordered by dragging and dropping the section headers, or by pressing <kbd>Alt+Up</kbd> / <kbd>Alt+Down</kbd> when a row is selected. The vertical header can be toggled by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>. The *logical* rows can be printed by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>.

**UPDATE**:

I also added support for moving sections around by dragging and dropping the rows themselves.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QModelIndex

class myModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None, *args):
        super().__init__(parent, *args)
        self._data = data or []
        self._headers = ['Type', 'result', 'count']

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return len(self._headers)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                if section < 0 or section >= len(self._headers):
                    return ""
                else:
                    return self._headers[section]
            else:
                return ''
        return None

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignHCenter
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            return QBrush(Qt.black)
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if (self.index(index.row(), 0).data().startswith('second')):
                return QBrush(Qt.green)
            else:
                if (self.index(index.row(), 1).data()) == 'abc':
                    return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
                if (self.index(index.row(), 1).data()) == 'def':
                    return QBrush(Qt.blue)
                if (self.index(index.row(), 1).data()) == 'ghi':
                    return QBrush(Qt.magenta)
        if role in (Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole):
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled

    def supportedDropActions(self) -> bool:
        return Qt.MoveAction | Qt.CopyAction

class myTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        header = self.verticalHeader()
        header.setSectionsMovable(True)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed)
        header.setFixedWidth(10)
        QShortcut('F7', self, self.getLogicalRows)
        QShortcut('F6', self, self.toggleVerticalHeader)
        QShortcut('Alt+Up', self, lambda: self.moveRow(True))
        QShortcut('Alt+Down', self, lambda: self.moveRow(False))
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.SingleSelection)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if (event.source() is not self or
            (event.dropAction() != Qt.MoveAction and
             self.dragDropMode() != QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)):
            super().dropEvent(event)
        selection = self.selectedIndexes()
        from_index = selection[0].row() if selection else -1
        to_index = self.indexAt(event.pos()).row()
        if (0 <= from_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            0 <= to_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            from_index != to_index):
            header = self.verticalHeader()
            from_index = header.visualIndex(from_index)
            to_index = header.visualIndex(to_index)
            header.moveSection(from_index, to_index)
            event.accept()
        super().dropEvent(event)

    def toggleVerticalHeader(self):
        self.verticalHeader().setHidden(self.verticalHeader().isVisible())

    def moveRow(self, up=True):
        selection = self.selectedIndexes()
        if selection:
            header = self.verticalHeader()
            row = header.visualIndex(selection[0].row())
            if up and row > 0:
                header.moveSection(row, row - 1)
            elif not up and row < header.count() - 1:
                header.moveSection(row, row + 1)

    def getLogicalRows(self):
        header = self.verticalHeader()
        for vrow in range(header.count()):
            lrow = header.logicalIndex(vrow)
            index = self.model().index(lrow, 0)
            print(index.data())


class sample_data(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tv = myTableView(self)
        tv.setModel(myModel([
            ["first", 'abc', 123],
            ["second"],
            ["third", 'def', 456],
            ["fourth", 'ghi', 789],
        ]))
        self.setCentralWidget(tv)
        tv.setSpan(1, 0, 1, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(['Test'])
    test = sample_data()
    test.setGeometry(600, 100, 350, 185)
    test.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @ekhumoro, your example works when dragging and dropping from the vertical header sidebar, is there a way to drag/drop by selecting the row itself that you know of?  Either way, you have got me a step forward, thank you.

Comment: @MikG I have added drag/drop support by adapting your drop-event handler so that it moves the sections instead. See my updated answer.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.  I'll take some time to learn what you have written, thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro, on reordering the rows I am noticing my self._data ordering isn't reflecting the visual changes of the moved rows.  So if I move the last row to say the second row, when I iterate through each row (e.g. for row in self._data) it skips second row and only executes the visual second row at the end (where it was previously the last row).  How is the best way to reflect the drag and drop in self._data as well?

Comment: @MikG As I said in my answer, the underlying model is never modified - the movements are purely *visual*. So you simply need to translate between [logical](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#logicalIndex) and [visual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#visualIndex) indices to get the required row. This is a deliberate part of the design, since it allows the original state to be restored.

Comment: I tried calling the relocateRow method I had in my example towards the end of dropEvent method, but without successfully reordering the model data.  I should've mentioned that I am not concerned with restoring the original order

Comment: @MikG Your question shows a *read-only* model, so my assumption was that the reordering of the rows should preserve that condition. Why do you need to modify the underlying model? Why can't you just translate between the indices? It's a lot simpler to do things that way.

Comment: @MikG Ps: if the code in your question is just a toy example and your real application is different, I think you need to make that clear. Otherwise we will just end up talking past each other. It's not impossible to achieve what you want, but the exact solution will very likely depend on what your real application looks like.

Comment: I thought I should reduce the example as my real version contains over 18 columns.  My plan was to iterate over each row, to construct an XML using parameters captured from some of the columns, and then send the XML to a server, before moving on to the next row.  But at the same time allowing the user to change the order of the rows to a preferred XML sequence.  The single spanned row was to introduce added options like a row to set a delay, before moving on to the next row.  So ideally keeping the model data in order is preferable to keep track of the reordered sequence.

Comment: @MikG Your description seems to imply that modifying the model isn't necessary, since the table isn't user-editable (apart from the re-ordering of rows). In which case, all you need to do is translate the indices, which can be wrapped up in a simple convenience method. So to get the required order, iterate over the rows *as they are displayed in the view*, and then translate from visual to logical indices.

Comment: Generally the table isn't user editable, but one or two columns would be.  For example one column is a time out duration based on waiting for the server to respond.  I was hoping to allow the user to at least edit this column if they felt the time out was too long.

Comment: @MikG But the user can't change the overall structure of the table, other than by reordering the rows, right? It's not freely editable like a spreadsheet, correct? Have you tried translating the indices as I suggested? It's such a simple solution that I can't see any need to complicate things any further.

Comment: @MikG If you bear with me, I will try to add something to my example to illustrate how simple this can be.

Comment: So sorry about this, and thank you for your extended help, i'm only at the beginnings of my understanding of using qtableview and models.  My only worry about not shifting the model data to match the table row is when I come to updating the row (e.g. programmatically setting a column to 'PASS'), is if the mapping through iterating through each row doesn't correspond to the same item in the model data.  In my mind it was easier to keep track of things by aligning the visual table rows with the model data

Comment: @MikG Reordering sections simply rearranges the indexes in the header (which has its own model). Effectively, these header indexes are acting like *pointers* to the rows in the table. Any editing of the *contents* of the table cells is completely independant of this. The view records the user's visual reordering of the header sections whilst keeping note of the original logical index. So when you need to pull the data out of your model, you can just iterate over the vertical header and get the corresponding table model index by translating from visual to logical rows.

Comment: @MikG See the `getLogicalRows` method in my updated answer for a basic implementation of this approach (press F7 to print the output).

Comment: I had an attempt, but I think my plan falls down as I have several row += 1 references in my code, unless there's a '.next' option for the vertical header?

Comment: @MikG You mean `header.logicalIndex(row) + 1` or `header.logicalIndex(row + 1)`? At the risk of repeating myself *ad nauseum*, all you need to do is translate the visual rows into logical rows. It really is that simple.

Comment: Sorry, was just about to reply with the same solution.  Sorry about that, and thanks again

Comment: @MikG No problem. It does take a while to get used to the idea of working with views. Personally, I usually create some generic convenience methods (or an adapter class) for handling the index translations so I don't have to remember when to do them.