# PyQt5 dragging and dropping in QTableview causes selected row to disappear

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qtableview

Following on from a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69042483/re-ordering-qtableview-rows-that-include-spanned-columns), I looked to add delete row on key press functionality to my qtableview table in PyQt5 by adding the removeRows function to my model.  However, since adding this function it has disrupted my drag and drop functionality, whereby the dragged row disappears when dropping elsewhere in the qtableview table.
Is there anyway I can prevent the dragged row from disappearing?

NB: Interestingly, when selecting the vertical header 'column' the drag/drop functionality works, but I'm keen to find a solution for dragging and dropping on row selection.

Here's my code below with the added removeRows function in the model, and also the keyPressEvent in the view

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt, QModelIndex

class myModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None, *args):
        super().__init__(parent, *args)
        self._data = data or []
        self._headers = ['Type', 'result', 'count']

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return len(self._headers)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                if section < 0 or section >= len(self._headers):
                    return ""
                else:
                    return self._headers[section]
            else:
                return ''
        return None

    def removeRows(self, position, rows, QModelIndex):
        self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex, position, position + rows - 1)
        for i in range(rows):
            del (self._data[position])
        self.endRemoveRows()
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        return True

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return Qt.AlignHCenter
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            return QBrush(Qt.black)
        if role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if (self.index(index.row(), 0).data().startswith('second')):
                return QBrush(Qt.green)
            else:
                if (self.index(index.row(), 1).data()) == 'abc':
                    return QBrush(Qt.yellow)
                if (self.index(index.row(), 1).data()) == 'def':
                    return QBrush(Qt.blue)
                if (self.index(index.row(), 1).data()) == 'ghi':
                    return QBrush(Qt.magenta)
        if role in (Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole):
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> Qt.ItemFlags:
        return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled

    def supportedDropActions(self) -> bool:
        return Qt.MoveAction | Qt.CopyAction


class myTableView(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        header = self.verticalHeader()
        header.setSectionsMovable(True)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed)
        header.setFixedWidth(10)
        QShortcut('F7', self, self.getLogicalRows)
        QShortcut('F6', self, self.toggleVerticalHeader)
        QShortcut('Alt+Up', self, lambda: self.moveRow(True))
        QShortcut('Alt+Down', self, lambda: self.moveRow(False))
        self.setSelectionBehavior(self.SelectRows)
        self.setSelectionMode(self.SingleSelection)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if (event.source() is not self or
            (event.dropAction() != Qt.MoveAction and
             self.dragDropMode() != QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)):
            super().dropEvent(event)
        selection = self.selectedIndexes()
        from_index = selection[0].row() if selection else -1
        to_index = self.indexAt(event.pos()).row()
        if (0 <= from_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            0 <= to_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            from_index != to_index):
            header = self.verticalHeader()
            from_index = header.visualIndex(from_index)
            to_index = header.visualIndex(to_index)
            header.moveSection(from_index, to_index)
            event.accept()
        super().dropEvent(event)

    def toggleVerticalHeader(self):
        self.verticalHeader().setHidden(self.verticalHeader().isVisible())

    def moveRow(self, up=True):
        selection = self.selectedIndexes()
        if selection:
            header = self.verticalHeader()
            row = header.visualIndex(selection[0].row())
            if up and row > 0:
                header.moveSection(row, row - 1)
            elif not up and row < header.count() - 1:
                header.moveSection(row, row + 1)

    def getLogicalRows(self):
        header = self.verticalHeader()
        for vrow in range(header.count()):
            lrow = header.logicalIndex(vrow)
            index = self.model().index(lrow, 0)
            print(index.data())

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Delete:
            index = self.currentIndex()
            try:
                self.model().removeRows(index.row(), 1, index)
            except IndexError:
                pass
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)


class sample_data(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tv = myTableView(self)
        tv.setModel(myModel([
            ["first", 'abc', 123],
            ["second"],
            ["third", 'def', 456],
            ["fourth", 'ghi', 789],
        ]))
        self.setCentralWidget(tv)
        tv.setSpan(1, 0, 1, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(['Test'])
    test = sample_data()
    test.setGeometry(600, 100, 350, 185)
    test.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main "problem" is that, by default, `removeRows` of QAbstractItemModel doesn't do anything (and returns `False`).

The *technical* problem is a bit more subtle.
A drag operation in an item view always begins with [`startDrag()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#startDrag), which creates a QDrag object and calls its `exec()`. When the user drops the data, that implementation also calls a private `clearOrRemove` function whenever the accepted drop action is `MoveAction`, which eventually overwrites the data *or* removes the row(s).

You've used `setDragDropOverwriteMode(False)`, so it will call `removeRows`. Your previous code used to work because, as said, the default implementation does nothing, but now you've reimplemented it, and it actually deletes rows in that case.

The solution is to change the drop action whenever the drop event is a move (which is a bit unintuitive, but since the operation has been already performed, that shouldn't be an issue). Using `IgnoreAction` will avoid the unwanted behavior, as that `clearOrRemove` won't be called anymore in that case:

```
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        # ...
        if (0 <= from_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            0 <= to_index < self.model().rowCount() and
            from_index != to_index):
            # ...
            header.moveSection(from_index, to_index)
            event.accept()
            event.setDropAction(Qt.IgnoreAction)
        super().dropEvent(event)
```

**UPDATE**

When the items don't fill the whole viewport, drop events can occur outside the items range, resulting in an invalid QModelIndex from `indexAt()` not only when dropping beyond the last row, but also the last column.
Since you're only interested in vertical movement, the solution is to get the `to_index` from the vertical header, and eventually set it to the last row whenever it's still invalid (-1):

```
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if (event.source() is not self or
            (event.dropAction() != Qt.MoveAction and
             self.dragDropMode() != QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)):
            super().dropEvent(event)
        selection = self.selectedIndexes()
        from_index = selection[0].row() if selection else -1

        globalPos = self.viewport().mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        header = self.verticalHeader()
        to_index = header.logicalIndexAt(header.mapFromGlobal(globalPos).y())
        if to_index < 0:
            to_index = header.logicalIndex(self.model().rowCount() - 1)

        if from_index != to_index:
            from_index = header.visualIndex(from_index)
            to_index = header.visualIndex(to_index)
            header.moveSection(from_index, to_index)
            event.accept()
            event.setDropAction(Qt.IgnoreAction)
        super().dropEvent(event)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @musicamante, I would've never found that solution, even better that it's a one line solution!

Comment: I have noticed since implementing your fix above, whilst it works overall, I have noticed if you drag and drop a row just beyond the last row it also causes the row to disappear, is there a way to fix this problem easily?

Comment: @MikG see the update.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @musicmante, your updated solution works perfectly

Comment: Sorry to pester you again @musicamante, not sure if I should raise a second question, but I've now noticed that if I drag and drop a row to the bottom of the table (say the second row is moved to the bottom on the table), and then I key-press delete on the selected first row, the second row now shifts back to it's original position in the table, albeit now in the position of the top row, since the original top row was deleted. Do I need to add a new method to the view to refresh based on visible rows, rather than logical rows?

Comment: @MikG I didn't notice: your `removeRows` call is wrong: the parent argument of a table index cannot be the index itself: as the name suggests, it must be the *parent* of that index. For <= 2D models (aka: list or table models, not trees), it's usually a `QModelIndex()` (an invalid index, indicating the root). Change the definition of `removeRows` to `removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):`, change to `self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)` and then use `self.model().removeRows(index.row(), 1)` (with no parent argument!) in `keyPressEvent`.